# Visual C++ 2008 Express, Diagrams

Tags: diagramming, visual-c++-2008-express

I'd like to get a graphic bar diagram out of some data (Percentages) calculated.
I've found the following class:

```
System::Windows::Forms::AccessibleRole::Diagram.
```

The intellisense tells me the:

```
"A graphical Immage used to diagram data"
```

Ok, now how do I use this in order to design the diagram?
How do I tell the system the type of diagram I want and 
how do I associate the data to the varios bars?

Thanks and regards (hope to have expressed myself clear enough)

Uwe_98

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rx14eHnML1Q

Comment: thanks, but the element 'chart' isn't present in my toolbox. I'm working with VC++ 2008 Express Version. If You should have any other idea, pls. tell me.